# Obj-c/cocoa: When I click a button, an infinite loop starts, data appears corrupted?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Question originally posted here: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/objective-c/threads/453854/nstableview-is-not-updating-correctly
Also has full code.

GUI:

[image]

I'm using an NSMutableArray to store strings that populate a NSTableView on my form. I am using a button action to delete a specified row. Rows are specified with a value stored in an int, that updates when you click on the table.

when I click a button on my form it activates this method:

```
-(IBAction)removeFromList:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"count: %d, at: %d\n",count,at);
    if(at<count)
    {
          [list removeObjectAtIndex:at];
    }
    [_table reloadData];
    at=count+1;
    count--;
    [_label setStringValue:[self converttonsstring:at]];
}
```

Table points to table, removeFromList is called from remove, int at specifies which row is to be removed, list is NSMutableArray, count is total number of rows. _label points to label at bottom of screen, tells me where at is pointing to.
I get the following output:

```
2013-05-04 02:32:17.874 ToDoList[571:903] count: 7, at: 2
2013-05-04 02:32:34.763 ToDoList[571:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (6) beyond bounds (6)
```

last line repeats on and on. I don't know whats going on here or what I should look at. From what I can tell thats the only part of my project that doesn't work. Any help or what I should be looking at is really appreciated.

Comment: have you tried setting a break point in this method and stepping thru it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not decrementing the `count` variable after you remove the object from `list`, so `numberOfRowsInTableView:` will still return the old value, so that `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is called with a row that no longer exists in your array.

Comment: You were right. All I had to do was move the `count--;` in the if statement. I can see how that would limit my ability... oh wait a minute... So it was working this whole time but on rows that I couldn't see because count wasn't accurate ... wait that doesnt make sense. mmhm I'll take it.